# Is there some test/tests that I can easily use to gauge my level of "proficiency"?

Tags: english, proficiency-testing

Is there some test/tests that I can easily use to gauge my level of "proficiency"?

Without going to some costly test.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Language Learning Stack Exchange. If this is about English, as the tag suggests, please make this explicit in both the question title and the question body. In addition, can you also add whether you are looking specifically for an online test (since you write "easily") or any type of test?

Answer (score 0):

Use the language for whatever purpose you intend to and see how well it goes. This should give you a pretty good idea of your abilities.

Comment: But this would also require knowing, whether those rating it are "informed".

Comment: You misunderstand. Let us say you want to read English fantasy books. So you pick up a Conan story, Harry Potter and Lord of the rings and try to read them. Seeing how well you do gives you are idea of how close to your goal you are. You do not need anyone rating you.